# Stackoverflowexception with xUnit and dotnet CLI - which test?

Tags: stack-overflow, xunit, asp.net-core-cli

I'm using `dotnet` to run my unit tests in xUnit.

In one of my unit tests I get a Stackoverflow. How do I determine **which** unit test causes this?

Project.json (relevant parts):

```
 "dependencies": {
    "NLog": {
      "target": "project"
    },
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029"
  },
 "testRunner": "xunit",
  "frameworks": {
        "net451": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1"
            }
        }
  }
```

Running:

```
> dotnet test
```

Current result:

```
xUnit.net .NET CLI test runner (64-bit Desktop .NET win81-x64)
  Discovering: NLog.UnitTests
  Discovered:  NLog.UnitTests
  Starting:    NLog.UnitTests

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
SUMMARY: Total: 1 targets, Passed: 0, Failed: 1.
```

I'm using xUnit to run unit tests under .NET Core and .NET 4.5.1 (currently only .NET 4.5.1 used in the example)

PS: `dotnet test --verbose` does not exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it by running the test in Visual Studio. The GUI makes it clear which test was the issue.

Comment: In VS2019 v16.10 it isn't very obvious - when you start a large run and one of the test fails with a stackoverflow they'll all be shown as stale or not-started (which is demonstrably wrong...) - so you need to click on each stale/not-started test until you see which one failed, ugh  -or dig through the Tests output window.